# how do add a dialog to the bootstrap 4 modal button rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have added a bootstrap modal to my rails 5 app successfully however I am trying to add a dialog similar to other rails form to ask them to confirm if they wish to continue. With this modal I need to to get a question with a cancel or cont that will then fire the modal. For example they press redeem then prior to showing the modal a question will appear. "do you wish to cont your offer will be redeemed. I have used the code below in the past with rails however do not know how to apply it to bootstrap modal.

```
<%= link_to theme_icon_tag("trash"), deal_path(deal), 'data-toggle': 
'tooltip', title: 'Delete',data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, method: 
:delete, class: 'btn btn-link' %>
```

my research has shown only how to use modal as the dialog alert itself. Do I have to use a modal inside a modal. Or is there a JS or bootstrap code to achieve this

my modal code below:

```
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block" data- 
toggle="modal" data-target="#redeem">Redeem Now</button>

<div id="redeem" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data- 
   dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"><%= @deal.deal_title %></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Your coupon code is <%= @deal.promo_code %>. You just saved 
         a bunch of mullah $$$$</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data- 
      dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want a confirm dialog with redeem or cancel and if the user press redeem then you want to show the modal, right?

Comment: Yes with a message above the response "do you wish to proceed your offer will be redeemed"

Answer (score 0):

> For example they press redeem then prior to showing the modal a
>   question will appear. "do you wish to cont your offer will be
>   redeemed.

**Solution #1:**

You can have a link which will ask the users to redeem or not like so

```
<%= link_to "Redeem", "#", class: 'btn btn-link redeem-link', data: { confirm: 'Do you wish to proceed your offer will be redeemed' } %>
```

then with the Jquery, trigger the modal like so

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.redeem-link').click(function() {
    if (confirm('Do you wish to proceed your offer will be redeemed')) // If user clicks ok
    {
      $("#redeem").modal('show'); // This will open the modal
    }
    else{
    }
  });
});
```

**Solution #2:**

A better way to handle such scenarios is with [*jquery-confirm*](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/) plugin. This ships with many options which come very handy.

Import it via CDN

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.0/jquery-confirm.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.0/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
```

Have a link which will trigger the confirm box

```
<%= link_to "Redeem", "#", class: 'btn btn-link redeem-link' %>
```

Add the below jquery code and you are good to go

```
$(".redeem-link").confirm({
  title: 'Do you wish to proceed your offer will be redeemed',
  buttons: {
    confirm: function () {
      $("#redeem").modal('show'); // This will open the modal
    },
    cancel: function () {
      $.alert('Canceled!');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Where does the link <%= link_to "Redeem", "#", class: 'btn btn-link redeem-link' %> go in relation too my initial button that triggers the modal?

Comment: I replaced the<button type="button" ..> with the <%= link_to "Redeem"..> and option 1 worked to certain degree as the modal was viewed upon confirm although only flashed for few seconds then disappeared as if closed. option two noting happens when button pressed. in console: Uncaught Error: jquery-confirm requires jQuery at jquery-confirm.min.js:10 .

Comment: @Zurch For the option 2 error place `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` above the jquery confirm script

Comment: @Zurch For option 1, place a debugger upon model show and check what is leading to that behavior of modal closing by itself.

Comment: option 2 now has a different error I passed the script above jquery-confirm and the  console stating:Uncaught TypeError: $(...).confirm is not a function and when redeem is pressed:                                  
  at <anonymous>:3:23
    at r.assignNewBody (turbolinks.self-2db6ec539b9190f75e1d477b305df53d12904d5cafdd47c7ffd91ba25cbec128.js?body=1:6)
    at r.replaceBody (turbolinks.self-2db6ec539b9190f75e1d477b305df53d12904d5cafdd47c7ffd91ba25cbec128.js?body=1:6)